# Item dissapears from Ienumerable List when performing an Interface Method on part of the collection

Tags: c#, interface, devexpress, controls, ienumerable

When iterating through a list of Controls, if the Control uses the Interface `ISaveTab`, it will have the method `SaveData();` used on it

However, for a certain item in this Ienumerable, it will always dissapear from the IEnumerable List `xtcPersonnelTabs.TabPages`

I have found that this item will always dissapear whenever another item in the list is modified. For example, if there are two items in my list, upon the first line running the `((ISaveTab)p.Cotrols[0]).SaveData();` The Ienumerable list will actually lose the second entry, and so the application will crash with the error

"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

```
foreach (XtraTabPage p in xtcPersonnelTabs.TabPages)
{
    if (p.Controls[0] is ISaveTab)
    {
        myNote = (((ISaveTab)p.Controls[0]).NeedsSave());
        myNote.FormNoteTab = ((ISaveTab)p.Controls[0]);

        if (myNote.FormNeedsSave == 1)
        {
            if (myNote.FormHasMandy)
            {
                myNoteGroup.FormNeedsSave = 1;
                myNoteGroup.FormNoteGroup.Add(myNote);
            }
            else
            {
                ((ISaveTab)p.Controls[0]).SaveData();
                hasSaved = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging the cause of the issue is causing me problems, as the `.SaveData();` method is run on another form, and so i lose the ability to see at which point the item drops out of my Ienumerable, which is at that point on the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this could be caused by:

By iterating over or accessing an element from an `IEnumerable` multiple times you are effectively calling the method to enumerate the `IEnumerable` multiple times.

So supposing that `.SaveData();` removes the element from the collection, then when you come to access the `IEnumerable` again the enumeration will be enumerated again, but this time the element removed in `SaveData` will no longer be there.

For example:

```
var enumerable = GetData();
enumerable[0].SaveData();
```

On second call of `GetData();` the saved element will not be returned, so the second time you access the enumerable there would not be a second element.

If you first force the enumeration to a list or array using:

```
var asList = enumerable.ToList();
var asArray = enumerable.ToArray();
```

Then iterate over/modify elements on the list or array, you should not find that the elements go missing.

For more on the multiple enumeration of the `IEnumerable`, see:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Possible+multiple+enumeration+of+IEnumerable

Comment: I found out the problem!

There was an EntityChanged event being run against a reguarly used database table, that would remove and re-add tabs into the tab list under very specific circumstances.

This was coded in wrong under the circumstance i was using, and would accidentally delete a tab that should never be deleted.

However this answer was insightful and useful nontheless! thanks for the suggestions